# Quickfix changing sequence number

Tags: java, quickfix

I need to lower my received sequence number for performing FIX certification to check the gap fill/resend works.

I tried editing the number but now I get `EOF Exception` whenever I launch my app.

The format of the sequence number file is a bit weird:

```
^@^C7:4
```

Any idea how to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: And with what did you edit it? It's likely a binary file, not a text file, so you can't edit it with, say, Notepad and expect it to work.

Comment: I tried notepad and also nano in cygwin. How else can you edit it?

Comment: To edit a binary file you need a binary editor *and* deep knowledge of how the file is made.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    int senderSequenceNumber=1910;
    int targetSequenceNumber=2268;
    RandomAccessFile file  = new RandomAccessFile("C:\\filename.seqnums", "rw");
    file.seek(0);
    file.writeUTF("" + senderSequenceNumber + ':'+ targetSequenceNumber);
}
```

This is adapted from quickfix.FileStore

Answer (score 0):

You can use the file.readUTF() to print the sequence number string.

```java
        RandomAccessFile seqFile  = new RandomAccessFile("/Users/jacky/test.seqnums", "r");
        System.out.println(seqFile.readUTF());
        seqFile.close();
```